# Close Vote Review reason shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, review

It would be nice if rather than having to open the close dialog to vote while reviewing close votes, we could just click on the reason listed to place a vote.

Comment: You might also like [this user script](https://gist.github.com/3105302), you can fork it and add the sites you need then use the raw link to install it.